# Access Recordset in Multiple Textboxes using ADO

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to fill my 31 textboxes with one single recordset containing 31 days (from Jan 1st to Jan 31st).

While it's clear for me how to assign each field of the query to the relevant textbox, it's not clear at all how to assign the several values contained in one single field of the query to multiple textboxes.

As for example, this is my starting code:

Private Sub FillDates()

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
ssql = "SELECT PricingDate From RoomCalendar WHERE PricingDate BETWEEN #01/01/2016# AND #31/01/2016# AND RateRoomCombinationId=17"
rst.Open ssql, cnn
Do Until rst.EOF = True

'txt1.Value = rst.Fields!PricingDate 
'txt2.Value = rst.Fields!PricingDate 
'txt3.Value = rst.Fields!PricingDate 

rst.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Record As Integer
Dim Records As Integer

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
ssql = "SELECT PricingDate From RoomCalendar WHERE PricingDate BETWEEN #2016/01/01# AND #2016/01/31# AND RateRoomCombinationId=17"

rst.Open ssql, CNN
rst.MoveLast
rst.MoveFirst
Records = rst.RecordCount
For Record = 1 To Records
    Me("txt" & CStr(Record)).Value = rst.Fields!PricingDate.Value 
    rst.MoveNext
Next
End Sub
```

Note please, the format for the date expressions.

Comment: Hi Gustav, thank you for your feedback however the above code is not working. It doesn't retrieve the data. Could you please give it an extra check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the question on my own. Final code is:

```
Private Function FillDates()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ssql As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim i As Integer
Dim Records As Integer
ssql = "SELECT PricingDate From RoomCalendar WHERE PricingDate BETWEEN #2016/01/01# AND #2016/01/31# AND RateRoomCombinationId=17"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.Open ssql, cnn
Records = rst.RecordCount
For i = 1 To Records
    Me("Text" & i).Value = rst.Fields!PricingDate.Value
    rst.MoveNext
Next i
   '' Clean up
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

Thanks for your help